# Mysql index in left join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am using symfony and sonata admin bundle, and in the Admin part I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a0_.id AS id_0, 
  a0_.home_position AS home_position_1 
FROM article_en a0_ 
LEFT JOIN fos_user_user f1_ ON a0_.author_id = f1_.id 
ORDER BY a0_.home_position DESC 
LIMIT 25 
OFFSET 0
```

The query around  1 second, it too much an the `article_en` table its around 25.000 rows.  I want to improve the performance of this query using some index but all my attempts are not success.

Any advice to improve performance?

EDIT

I explain the structure of the tables in the database. This is the **article_en** table, structure and index:

[Article_en table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gay3.png)

Index are:

- Primary and unique in id
- Index in position
- Index in home_position
- Index in publication_date enable
- Index in author_id
- Foreign key in author_id
- Foreign key in arabic_id, dutch_id, german_id ...

And this is the **fos_user_user table**:

[Fos_user_user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pezC.png)

Index are:

- Primary and Unique in id.
- Unique in username_canonical
- Unique in email_canonical
- Index in id

**Plan**

This query is executed by sonata admin bundle when is going to show the latest 25 english articles from a specific user . I executed this query each time in the sonata admin bundle, this query is executed in a paginated pattern, my goal is try to improve the performance of this query to improve the user experience in this part of the app.

Comment: Could you improve readability of the query?

Comment: Post the Explain plan for above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add index on 3 columns `a0_.author_id`, `f1_.id` and `a0_.home_position`

Index on `a0_.home_position` because it is used for sorting the results.

Comment: Do you mean individual index in each column? I already add this three index and is the same time.

Comment: Is datatype of columns `a0_.author_id` and `f1_.id` exact same? If you post your table structure and `explain` plan, we will be able to help you better.

Comment: Yes, is the same. It is a foreign key to this table. I Just posted the table and the plan.

Comment: `Explain` plan means query explanation, i.e., add `EXPLAIN` keyword before your query, execute it and post it's response.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just added an index to author_id and home_position and right now the query is really faster. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to help :)